# Pulltorefresh и ActionBar

Tags: actionbar, android, pulltorefresh

Как добавить поддержку `actionBar` в проект, в котором присуствует реализация `pulltorefresh` от криса бэйнса? Я использую `android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity`, но когда начинаю наследовать `Activity` от `ACtionBarActivity` приложение крашится

лог:

```
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.post_req/com.example.post_req.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:102)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:58)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:98)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at com.example.post_req.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-30 04:30:50.345: E/AndroidRuntime(2225):     ... 11 more
08-30 04:31:01.836: I/Process(2225): Sending signal. PID: 2225 SIG: 9
08-30 04:43:27.646: D/dalvikvm(2362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 75K, 7% free 2696K/2892K, paused 52ms, total 56ms
08-30 04:43:27.656: I/dalvikvm-heap(2362): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.352MB for 635812-byte allocation
08-30 04:43:27.797: D/dalvikvm(2362): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 6% free 3315K/3516K, paused 137ms, total 137ms
08-30 04:43:28.020: D/PullToRefresh(2362): Setting Padding. L: 0, T: 0, R: 0, B: 0
08-30 04:43:28.020: D/PullToRefresh(2362): First Visible: 0. Visible Count: 0. Total Items:0
08-30 04:43:28.346: D/PullToRefresh(2362): onSizeChanged. W: 480, H: 690
08-30 04:43:28.386: D/PullToRefresh(2362): Setting Padding. L: 0, T: -414, R: 0, B: 0
08-30 04:43:28.386: D/PullToRefresh(2362): First Visible: 0. Visible Count: 0. Total Items:0
08-30 04:43:28.406: I/Choreographer(2362): Skipped 67 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-30 04:43:28.487: D/gralloc_goldfish(2362): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 04:43:28.936: D/PullToRefresh(2362): First Visible: 0. Visible Count: 0. Total Items:0
08-30 04:43:35.566: D/PullToRefresh(2362): First Visible: 0. Visible Count: 10. Total Items:11
08-30 04:43:43.886: D/PullToRefresh(2362): First Visible: 0. Visible Count: 10. Total Items:11
08-30 04:43:44.195: I/Choreographer(2362): Skipped 54 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: Ну и уже ставший традиционным ответ: покажите стэктрэйс исключения.

Comment: добавил лог

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В логе недвусмысленно говорится, что вам следует использовать `Theme.AppCompat`:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

О чём говорится, кстати, и в [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html):

> Base class for activities that use the support library action bar features.
>
> You can add an ActionBar to your activity when running on API level 7 or higher by extending this class for your activity **and setting the activity theme to Theme.AppCompat or a similar theme**.

Укажите для тега `application` в `AndroidManifest.xml` атрибут `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"`. Или одно из остальных возможных значений, который вы можете посмотреть в документации, опять-таки.